# SQL Query Stored Procedure Errors

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm creating an e-commerce benchmark website. I have some problems in my GETSITES stored procedure:

Code:

```
CREATE PROC USER_S_GETSITES
   @CategoryID int,
   @List int,
   @IsPopular bit,
   @MaxID int,
   @Status bit,
   @Word text
AS
    SELECT s.*, c.*, AVG(r.Rate) AS RateAVG, Count(r.ID) AS RateCount 
    FROM Sites AS s
    INNER JOIN Rates AS r ON r.SiteID = s.ID
    INNER JOIN Categories AS c ON c.ID = s.CategoryID
    WHERE (@CategoryID is NULL) OR s.CategoryID = @CategoryID
      AND (@MaxID is NULL) OR s.ID < @MaxID
      AND (@Status is NULL) OR s.Status = @Status
      AND r.Status=1
      AND (@Word is NULL) OR s.Name LIKE @Word OR s.Description LIKE @Word
      AND (@IsPopular is NULL) OR s.IsPopular=@IsPopular 
ORDER BY
    CASE @List WHEN 1 THEN s.ID END ASC,
    CASE @List WHEN 2 THEN s.ID END DESC,
    CASE @List WHEN 3 THEN RateAVG END DESC,
    CASE @List WHEN 4 THEN RateCount END DESC
```

And my problems :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USER_S_GETSITES, Line 9
>   Column 'Sites.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USER_S_GETSITES, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'RateAVG'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USER_S_GETSITES, Line 24
>   Invalid column name 'RateCount'.

I can't solve these problems. What should I do?

Comment: Columns without aggregate functions(SUM,COUNT etc) must be in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Every non aggregate column must be mentioned in the group by clause, which I suspect means you are not going to get the numbers you want seeing as you are selecting every column in sites and categories. Usual way of doing this sort of thing. Is to have an aggregate query and group by it's unique keys and then join back to the original data by that / those keys.

Comment: I havent solve this problem yet 'cause i didnt understand. Can you write sample SQL code please?

Answer (score 1):

Error 1: include column `Sites.ID` in `GROUP BY` clause like `group by Sites.ID, ....`

Error 2: `CASE @List WHEN 3 THEN AVG(r.Rate) AS RateAVG END DESC`

Error 3: `CASE @List WHEN 4 THEN Count(r.ID) AS RateCount END DESC`